# Why am I getting seemingly duplicate “arp-scan DUP(:x)” results when running “arp-scan”

Tags: linux, networking, home-networking, localhost, duplicate

I have searched for the information but could not find an answer to my question.

So I ran this command on my laptop:

```
sudo arp-scan --interface=eth0 --localnet
```

And got some weird results:

```
ip  mac_address Raspberry Pi Foundation
ip  mac_address Raspberry Pi Foundation (DUP: 2)
```

Same thing for the Netatmo device, the IP and MAC addresses are the same but what does it mean, why are they duplicated. I checked [man arp-scan](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/arp-scan.1.html) and it says something about duplicates but why are they there for these “Internet of Things” devices.

I heard “Internet of Things” devices are more susceptible to get hacked so that is why I would like to know more.

Comment: If you are on your local LAN and doing this, I doubt these “Internet of Things” devices are being hacked. The main reason “Internet of Things” devices get hacked is because people don’t see them as servers and thus — when they are deployed outside of a LAN — they are not hardened in any way. Such as devices with Mongo DBs on them having no passwords or restrictions and such. Past that there is no inherent risks. This is most likely a duplicate broadcast of ARP traffic and nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add -g to the command.
`sudo arp-scan --interface=eth0 --localnet -g`
All basic option are in the help `arp-scan -h`